# Interpreting result of OrdinalGEE

Tags: generalized-estimating-equations, ordered-logit, statsmodels

I am trying to understand the IPython notebook [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/umich.box.com/shared/static/y1fw0iameuixrq9zt02d.ipynb?create=1).  The output of the GEE fit displays:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I(y>0.0)       3.1493      0.039     80.567      0.000         3.073     3.226
I(y>2.0)       1.9428      0.031     62.975      0.000         1.882     2.003
I(y>4.0)       0.8754      0.028     31.262      0.000         0.821     0.930
I(y>6.0)      -0.2568      0.028     -9.070      0.000        -0.312    -0.201
I(y>8.0)      -1.6892      0.033    -51.327      0.000        -1.754    -1.625
Gender        -0.5722      0.032    -18.041      0.000        -0.634    -0.510
Age           -0.0298      0.003     -9.751      0.000        -0.036    -0.024
GCSE           1.7411      0.026     66.114      0.000         1.689     1.793
```

What do the `I(y>...)` stand for?

Comment: Although asked in terms of Python, this is a statistical question. It should be considered on-topic here.

Comment: Seems to me it's just a factor variable. It's not specific to GEEs. I believe this is for the 'A-Score' factor.

My personal preference/suggestion: don't use Python for statistical modeling. The API for scipy/statmodels seems so funky to me. I would suggest doing this type of analysis using SPSS, R, Stata or even SAS.

Comment: I think they are the constants for the cumulative odds ordinal model, e.g. https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/176 In the latent variable interpretation they would be related to the constants that define the integration limits.